# Can't initialize drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, external-hard-drive

I have a 2.5" laptop harddrive that I plugged into my laptop through a SATA to USB cable.  It's powered by an adapter to a normal wall-plug.  I want to use it as an external harddrive.

It wouldn't initialize (Device is not ready), so as suggested in some instructions I found I uninstalled the drivers, unplugged it and plugged it back in.  That worked, and I initialized the drive and formatted it.

However I unplugged it after that and a few days later the same strategy does not work and I can't figure out how to use the drive.  I can't initialize it and it doesn't show up in my computer.

Comment: Every adapter of that type has a sequence to connect the drive, some want you to connect power before the usb cable is connected to the PC, some want it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Microsoft Fix It](http://support.microsoft.com/fixit/) a try - it fixed a problem I had when Win 7 wouldn't see the DVD drive. Worth a try.